# GWT: debug events capturing/bubbling

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I wonder if there is a way to perform a step-by-step debugging of the compiled GWT code, in order to determine how some events are being fired.

The interest I have on this is that I'm using SmartGWT, and for some reason the click events on their components propagate to pop up windows that occupy the same position. However this only happens in Mobile Safari.

Even more interesting it only happens with smartGWT version of onClick and not with the plain GWT onClick.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly a hack for now, but I suppose it'll work (you'll have to recompile your app though):

1. First, compile a recent GWT from trunk: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/makinggwtbetter#workingoncode
2. Then recompile your app with source maps enabled: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SourceMaps
3. Follow the steps in the comments of this wiki page to be able to use SourceMaps in Chrome, then re-deploy your app
4. Get Chrome on the Dev channel: http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel
5. Use http://www.iwebinspector.com/ to start Mobile Safari with remote debugging and then connect to it from your Chrome desktop: http://www.webkit.org/blog/1620/webkit-remote-debugging/
6. Finally, enable source maps in Chrome so you'll see your *Java* code in the Web Inspector!

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xJl22Kvgjg for a preview of the future of debugging with GWT, that will allow this kind of things in a much less *hackish* way in the *near* future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a nice way to debug compiled **javascript** GWT code, but why do you need it?

For described purpose it's better to use GWT development mode with debugging options. You can add the following parametres `e-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address={PORT},server=y,suspend=n` to the development mode running command, it will give an opportunity to add breakpoints to the cliend side GWT/SmardGWT source code. Then for debugging you should connect to port specified in parametres from your java IDE.

Debugging GWT https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging

Comment: Except I suppose you'll have a hard time finding a DevMode browser plugin for Mobile Safari ;-)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I have just missed this condition in the question.